# Не могу подключить пространство имен: "System.Windows" и "System.Xml.Linq"

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Мне необходимо создать простую программу на C#, которая:
Считывает данные из XML файла.
Если данные соответствуют условию, то открывает окно с DataGrid.
Если нет, то открывает окно с предупреждением, что данных нет.
Самое смешное, что я не знаю какой шаблон проекта выбрать в VisualStudio 2019.
Если "Empty Project", то он создается без "точки входа".
Если я создаю класс "Program" с методом "Main", то не могу подключить пространство имен: "System.Windows" и "System.Xml.Linq".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед подключением пространств имён необходимо добавить ссылки на советующие сборки. В Visual Studio для этого нужно нажать на папку проекта `Ссылки` или `References` правой кнопкой мыши, затем на `Добавить ссылку` или `Add reference` и отметить checkbox-ами те сборки, которые вы планируете использовать.

Узнать, в какой сборке находится нужный вам тип, можно на MSDN или в документации соответствующих библиотек.

Comment: aa_talanin, большое спасибо, заработало!

Comment: @ДмитрийРусаков, если помогло, примите ответ галкой слева. Спасибо.